# Creating subspec in podspec using kmm

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform, podspec, subspec

couldn't create subspecs in ios podspec in kmm

I am trying to create a subspec in podspec using kmm.

this is my build.gradle. this generates podspec mentioned below

```
cocoapods {
        summary = "Library"
        homepage = ""
        authors = ""
        ios.deploymentTarget = "11.1"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            isStatic = true
            baseName = "fw"
        }
    }
```

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.name                     = 'fw'
    spec.homepage                 = ''
    spec.source                   = { :http=> ''}
    spec.summary                  = 'Library'
    spec.libraries                = 'c++'
    spec.ios.deployment_target = '11.1'
                
    spec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
        'KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH' => ':fw',
        'PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME' => 'fw',
    }
```

I want to specify a folder named 'notification' as subspec. the above podspec is generated and if I try to add subspec in podspec file, it get deleted after rebuild project.